# Routing values to the MVC Player function?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, c1-cms

In a Composite C1 application, I am trying to pass values from the URL to the MVC Player function, but I have trouble because the values are part of the path and not in the query string.

The URL looks like this:

```
/AuctionDetailsGallery/3624734/Test-Versteigerung-2
```

AuctionDetailsGallery is a Composite C1 Page which includes the MvcPlayer function.
3624734 is the (dynamic) ID, "Test-Versteigerung-2" is a userfriendly name

The MvcPlayer is then supposed to call

```
/AuctionViewer/FilterGalleryPositions
```

("AuctionViewer" is the controller and "FilterGalleryPositions" the action.)

The ID has to be passed to the action, but under a different name ("SelectedAuctions").

So essentially, if the user calls

```
/AuctionDetailsGallery/3624734/Test-Versteigerung-2
```

I want to render the MVC action

```
/AuctionViewer/FilterGalleryPositions?SelectedAuctions=3624734
```

How can I do this?

I set the MvcPlayer path to `"/AuctionViewer/FilterGalleryPositions"` and played around with the routes, but I always get the message

> The controller for path '/3624734/Test-Versteigerung-2' was not found
>   or does not implement IController.

That's because the Render function checks for PathInfo and replaces the Path I set with the PathInfo if available. I guess it would be more useful if the PathInfo was appended, but I am unsure how to route my values with the current MVC Player implementation.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Erm, I am not sure why you made that edit. I am pretty sure that this isn't a bug, it's the way the C1 MvcPlayer works. I just don't know how to make my scenario work with that functionality.

Comment: Sorry about that, meant to make it to your *other* post about Composite C1. Although having the source code helps here too.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly I believe you are asking about routes.

With Attribute routing simply declare the route over the controller action (assuming controller name is AuctionViewerController):

```
[Route("AuctionDetailsGallery/{selectedAuctions}/Test-Versteigerung-2")]
public ActionResult FilterGalleryPositions(int selectedAuctions)
{
...
}
```

With a routetable you might define something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "AuctionDetails",
   url: "AuctionDetailsGallery/{selectedAuctions}/Test-Versteigerung-2",
   defaults: new { controller = "AuctionViewer", action = "FilterGalleryPositions" }
);
```

Comment: I know about routes. The problem is that I can't route to the action directly. (as you propose) The action and view are embedded in a Composite page. So the request is routed to the Composite C1 page, which includes a MvcPlayer function with the according path to the action. Then I somehow have to get the values from the request URL to the action in the MvcPlayer action.

Comment: Just to be clear: This is a Composite C1 CMS question. I doubt this can be solved by vanilla MVC means without C1 knowledge. I asked in their forums already, but got no response.